# MVC Authorize Attribute One Time In Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is CustomAuthorizeAttribute class content:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         return (CurrentUser.IsInRole(MasterRole, ChildRole)) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize(MasterRole="Master")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
...
    [CustomAuthorize(ChildRole = "Child")]
    public ActionResult Slider()
    {
        return View();
    }
...
}
```

In this usage to CustomAuthorizeAttribute class ChildRole comin as "Child" it's OK but MasterRole coming null.

How can i define "MasterRole" just one time in controller, or is it posible?

I mean, its working as below syntax but i don't want to define MasterRole for every action as below:

```
    [CustomAuthorize(MasterRole = "Master", ChildRole = "Child")]
    public ActionResult Slider()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Since you're mentioning `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`, can you provide corresponding class' contents? Also I want to know if `ChildRole` should implement `MasterRole` rather than override it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i added content, also I have multiple controllers in project and MasterRole is unique for each controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that authorization attributes are evaluated on the controller before on the action you could abuse the authorize system a bit. You could set the master role on the context and then retrieve it in the authorize attribute on the action.

Add two new attributes like so:

```
public class SetMasterRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string MasterRole;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Items.Add("MasterRole", MasterRole);
        return true;
    }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string ChildRole;
    public string MasterRole;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MasterRole))
        {
            MasterRole = httpContext.Items["MasterRole"] as string;
        }

        return (CurrentUser.IsInRole(MasterRole, ChildRole)) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

And then set up your controller and actions like this:

```
[SetMasterRole(MasterRole = "Master")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(ChildRole = "Child")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```